# Read file name then call a function with python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read file name(A/B/C/D) and **call the convenable function for each file** in Files folder and then process the next file (pass automatically to the next file and function).

I have multiple files stored in ***File_folder*** folder:

Here is the directory structure:

```
       App/  
       ├─ main.py
       └─ Files/  
       |   └─B.txt
       |   └─A.xlsx
       |   └─D.xlsx    
       |   └─C.csv
       └─ File_output/
```

I have multiple functions stored in ***main.py***:

```
def A_fct(fileA):
    pass
def B_fct(fileB):
    pass
def C_fct(fileC):
    pass
def D_fct(fileD):
    pass
def E_fct(fileE):
    pass
def F_fct(fileF):
    pass
```

Example:

**read file Name** *B.txt* => **call** *B_fct*

**read file Name** *A.xlsx* => **call** *A_fct*

etc ...

How can i do this please!

I have read all the suggestions belows but still don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python function call with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431216/python-function-call-with-variable)

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431216/python-function-call-with-variable) where the function call is assigned to a variable

Comment: I already saw this answer and this is not what i need. I want to Automate the file reading and function applying

Comment: So what is your question? How to get the file's name? How to pass it to a function? It is not clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Different Functions in Python Based on Values in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293680/calling-different-functions-in-python-based-on-values-in-a-list)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes how to get the file name than call his adequate function

Comment: Which one is it? Those are two questions. SO questions should focus on one. Anyway, both of them are duplicates and already answered on this site. Please make sure to research before asking and only ask here as a last resort

Comment: First this: [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/6045800) then the link above

Comment: @Tomerikoo i will check this

Comment: @Prestige I edited my answer, hope it helps you figure out how to combine the 2 solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to call a certain function for each file depending on the name of the file

you can define a dict with the relationship `file_name => function`

```
name_to_func = {
    "A": A_fct,
    "B": B_fct,
    ...
}
```

then call the function with

```
name_to_func[file_name](file_name)
```

Edit:

Now I understand that you want to iterate over files in a folder, you can do that with `os.listdir(path)`.

for example, something like this:

```
import os

path = '/your/path/here'

name_to_func = {
    "A": A_fct,
    "B": B_fct
}

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_prefix = file_name.split('.')[0]
    name_to_func[file_prefix](file_name)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly but i want to pass automatically to the next file and function

Comment: @Prestige What issues are you having with writing a loop over the folder's files?

Comment: @Prestige I edited the post. Hope these edits helped you with your problem